# Spivak: $F(x)=\int_a^x \frac{f(t)}{t}dt, x\geq 1$, Understanding proof that $f$ is bounded on $[1,\infty)$ $\iff$ $F/\log$ is bounded on $[1,\infty)$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, proof-explanation, logarithms

The following is a problem from Ch.18 of Spivak's *Calculus*. Though I came up with a solution, I cannot understand the solution manual solution, and would like to.

> 12. Let $f$ be a nondecreasing function on $[1,\infty)$, and define
>
> $$F(x)=\int_1^x \frac{f(t)}{t}dt, \text{ for }x\geq 1$$
>
> Prove that $f$ is bounded on $[1,\infty)$ if and only if $F/\log$ is
> bounded on $[1,\infty)$.

Solution Manual Solution

> If $|f|\leq M$ on $[1,\infty)$, then
>
> $$|F(x)|\leq \int_1^x \frac{|f(t)|}{t}dt\leq
>  M\int_1^x\frac{1}{t}dt=M\log{x}$$
>
> so $|F(x)|/\log{x}\leq M$ for all $x\geq 1$.

The above is fine. It is the converse that I would like to understand.

> To prove the converse, first suppose $f\geq 0$ on $[1,\infty)$. Then
> since $f$ is nondecreasing,
>
> $$F(x)=\int_1^x\frac{f(t)}{t}dt\leq f(x)\int_1^x\frac{1}{x}dt=
>  f(x)\log{x}$$
>
> so $|F/\log|$ bounded implies $|f|$ bounded.

Not sure about this last sentence. Didn't we show

$$f(x)\geq\frac{F(x)}{\log{x}}$$

How does this mean that $|f|$ is bounded?

> For the general case note that since $f$ is nondecreasing it is
> certainly bounded on any interval to the right of $1$ on which it is
> negative. If $f(b)=0$ for some $b>1$, then for $x\geq b$
>
> $$F(x)=\int_1^b \frac{f(t)}{t}dt+\int_b^x\frac{f(t)}{t}dt$$
>
> $$\leq \int_1^b\frac{f(t)}{t}dt+f(x)\int_b^x\frac{1}{t}dt$$
>
> $$=\int_1^b\frac{f(t)}{t}dt+f(x)[\log{x}-\log{b}]$$
>
> so
>
> $$\frac{F(x)}{\log{x}}=\frac{1}{\log{x}}\cdot \int_1^b
>  \frac{f(t)}{t}dt+\frac{\log{x}-\log{b}}{\log{x}}f(x)$$
>
> $$=A(x)+B(x)f(x), \text{ say }$$
>
> Then for $x\geq b$ we have
>
> $$|f(x)|\leq \frac{1}{|B(x)|}\left [ \left | \frac{F(x)}{\log{x}}
>  \right | +|A(x)| \right ]$$
>
> Now $|A(x)|$ is bounded (it $\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$] and $1/|B(x)|$
> is bounded [$B(x)\to 1$ as $x\to\infty$], so if $|F/\log|$ is bounded,
> then so is $|f|$.

**Here is my solution to the the converse, ie the proof of**

$$\frac{F}{\log} \text{ bounded on } [1,\infty) \implies f \text{ bounded on } [1,\infty)$$

Assume $\frac{F}{\log} \text{ bounded on } [1,\infty)$. Then for $x\in [1,\infty)$

$$\exists M, -M \leq \frac{\int_1^x \frac{f(t)}{t}dt}{\int_1^x t^{-1}dt}\leq M$$

$$ -M\int_1^x t^{-1}dt \leq \int_1^x \frac{f(t)}{t}dt\leq M\int_1^x t^{-1}dt\tag{1}$$

Assume, for proof by contradiction, that $f$ is not bounded on $[1,\infty)$.

Then for any number $N$ there is an $x$ such that $x\in[1,\infty)$ and $f(x)>N$.

Let $N=M$ and $x_1$ such that $x_1\in[1,\infty)$ and $f(x_1)>M$.

Then, since $f$ is nondecreasing, $\forall x, x>x_1 \implies f(x)\geq f(x_1)>M$.

Hence, $$\int_{x_1}^x \frac{f(t)}{t}dt>M\int_{x_1}^x t^{-1}dt$$

Let $x>x_1>1$. Then

$$\int_1^x \frac{f(t)}{t}dt=\int_1^{x_1}\frac{f(t)}{t}dt+\int_{x_1}^x \frac{f(t)}{t}dt>M\int_{x_1}^x t^{-1}dt$$

which contradicts $(1)$.

Therefore, by proof by contradiction, $f$ is bounded on $[1,\infty)$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

That quoted argument is indeed wrong. One can fix it as follows:
$$
F(x)=\int_1^x\frac{f(t)}{t}dt\geq f(\sqrt{x})\int_{\sqrt{x}}^x\frac{1}{x}dt= \frac 12 f(\sqrt{x})\log{x} 
$$
so that $F(x)/\log(x) \le M$ implies $f(\sqrt{x}) \le 2M$.

(The proof of the “general case” has the same flaw because a $\le$ mysteriously becomes $=$.)